# SQL In and having-clause, why do they produce different results?

Tags: sql, count, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

Considering the following relation `movie {country,major_genre,production_year, run_time, title`, I'd like to list all countries except Spain, the movies produced in that country, provided there are at least two of them.

I wrote two queries and they somehow produced different results. It seems that the first one is correct, but it seems to me that they are equal. I am learning SQL. Can someone please help to explain the differences? Thanks for your help!

The first one:

```
SELECT m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title
FROM movie m1
WHERE m1.country <> "Spain"
AND m1.country
IN (
    SELECT m2.country
    FROM movie m2
    GROUP BY m2.country        //select only the ones with at least 2 movies
    HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2
 )
ORDER BY m1.country ASC , m1.production_year DESC
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title
FROM movie m1
WHERE m1.country <> "Spain"
GROUP BY m1.country
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2  //the country selected should have count of at least 2 rows
ORDER BY m1.country ASC , m1.production_year DESC
```

Comment: My very first question is , Did the second query work ?

Comment: Looks like a MySQL query which is relaxed about the rules related to the GROUP BY clause. FYI, the second query is not correct, as you must list all the columns in the GROUP BY clause that are in the SELECT list

Comment: I am seeing  "m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title" in the select statement but whereas in the group by you have only  m1.country

Comment: yes the second one worked..

Comment: But after adding "m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title" to group by, it is still not correct

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second query uses `GROUP BY` on a single column, but returns 3 columns. So each country with > 1 movie comes out once, with a "random" value for year and movie (may not actually be random).

You can also do it without the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title
FROM movie m1
WHERE m1.country <> "Spain"
AND 1 < (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM movie m2
    WHERE m2.country = m1.country
  )
ORDER BY m1.country ASC , m1.production_year DESC
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2ddc/2

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to understand why the second one doesnt work. Even after I add `m1.country, m1.production_year, m1.title` to the GROUP BY, it is still incorrect.

Comment: Because the `COUNT(*)` applies to all the columns in the `GROUP BY`. So, in your original 2nd query, you are asking _summarize by country and only keep the countries with > 1 in the group_ then add year and title from somewhere. Which is why it doesn't quite work. You have already summarised rows down to one per country so you can't go back to having multiple per country.

Comment: If you ask to `GROUP BY` more columns, the `COUNT(*)` will no longer be what you want, because you are counting years and titles. You can't both group (by country) and include the things (year, title) you are ignoring for the group in a single step.